# default gateway of router is not it's ip

Tags: windows, networking, router, dns, ipv6

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2401:4900:eef:4031:9998:66e5:f48:9fd0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2401:4900:eef:4031:2ddc:156c:ee7d:2b31
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9998:66e5:f48:9fd0%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.234
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::4cc:bf5e:586c:c9f3%10
                                       192.168.43.1
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Why do you show the configuration of your WiFi adapter?

Comment: This configuration looks quite normal to me. Do you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: This question needs a lot more _question_. Please add more details. For now, I'm voting to close due to low quality.

Answer (score 0):

A different IP address between the interface and the default gateway is a normal setup.

The default gateway is the address of **another** node (typically a router) to which it should send a packet if it doesn’t belong to the subnet of its interface.

If you give a node its own address as a default gateway, it will send packet destinated far away to itself… the packet won’t get out of the node. Not really something you want.